# php add product post date woocommerce price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wanting to implement the following code snippet but want the suffix to the price on all products to read as per the example.

Example: $79.99 *As of 'product creation date'*

Code Snippet:

```
    <?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bg_price_prefix_suffix', 100, 2 );

function bg_price_prefix_suffix( $price, $product ){
    $price = 'prefix here ' . $price . ' suffix here';
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

I have found a code snippet that will echo the product post date after the product summary but am not sure how to use it for the suffix of the price. See below:

```
<?php    
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','bg_echo_product_date',25);

function bg_echo_product_date() {
if (is_product() ) {
echo the_date('', '<span class="date_published">Published on: ', '</span>', false);
}
}
```

I would also like to style the price suffix independently via css.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.date_published {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<?php
$price=7 9.99;
$prefex="$";
$suffex="November 11th, 2016";

// if you want a function you could do this. 
function productInfo($a, $b, $c) { 
   $date=a ddDate($c); return $a.$b.$date; 
} 

function addDate($date) { 
   return " <span class='date_published'> As of ".$date. "</span>"; 
} 

echo productInfo($prefex, $price, $suffex);

?>
```